# Batch file left string trim not working

Tags: batch-file

huge newbe.
I have two batch files that are working but when i try to combine them it fails.

First batch file searches a directory and copies file names as a variable...

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
cd I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder
set "files="
for /r %%F in (*) do call set files=%%files%% "%%F"
echo %files% | clip
```

In my case there is one file in the folder and it copies

"I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\Fotolia_93178533_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg"

### to the clipboard

The second batch file is meant to left trim a variable to just the left four characters. It works on its own.

```
set str=politic
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~0,4%
echo.%str%
```

---

But when I try to combine the two it is not working. Nothing gets written the the clipboard.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
cd I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder
set "files="
for /r %%F in (*) do call set files=%%files%% "%%F"
echo %files%
set files=%files:~0,4%
echo %files% | clip
```

Where is the error? Thanks, James

Comment: please explain what your expected output and end result is supposed to be. _You are aware that the %%F will be a full path, aren't you?. This means that %files% will be a probably extremely long single line list of filepath recursive files which will both quickly reach a limit and having the first four characters of the first full path will not achieve what you think you need._

Comment: @Compo everything you say is correct, but for all we know the OP could be just experimenting at this stage and he says there is only one file retrieved in the `for` command, so his variable is not going to overflow, but it is still not returning the expected result of the first four characters of the (one and only) path. (Actually the first two characters should be the space and the quote - but it's not even returning those for some reason.)

Comment: Hi again, Thanks for responses. Our system is set up so that there will only ever be one file in the examined folder. So the variable files should essentially be a text string which I then want to trim and then copy to the clipboard. I can get the files name to appear on the clipboard (it actually has a whitespace then the speech marks then the file name) But when I try to trim using set files=%files:~0,4% it all goes wrong.

Comment: That's a right trim.

Comment: If there was only ever one file then you wouldn't [**1.**] be using a recursive directory search [**2.**] calling the variable %files% [**3.**] adding %%F to the existing content of %files% after already ensuring that %files% starts empty.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is the way CMD.EXE works with variable expansion: it performs the expansion *before* it parses the command. So you have the variable `files` set to

"I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\Fotolia_93178533_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg"

and then the command `set files=%files:~0,4%` sets it to `"I:` - so it is missing the closing quote.

Then the command

```
echo %files% | clip
```

is actually seen as

```
echo  "I: | clip
```

and the pipe character `|` is treated as being part of the (unclosed) string.

I expect you probably don't want to clip the quote character, but the four characters after it: `set files=files:~2,4%` should do it. Otherwise, enable delayed expansion and use `!` instead of `%`.

Comment: Brilliant, that was the problem - removing the quotation marks surrounding the %%f at the end of line 5 seems to have worked - it's producing the expected result now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just want to do this at the **cmd.exe** prompt?

```dos
@For %A In ("I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\*.*") Do @Echo(%~dpnA|Clip
```

or with quotes:

```dos
@For %A In ("I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\*.*") Do @Echo("%~dpnA"|Clip
```

or even:

```dos
@For %A In ("I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\*.*") Do @Echo(%~pnxA|Clip
```

or with quotes:

```dos
@For %A In ("I:\Test\Batches\New folder (2)\New folder\*.*") Do @Echo("%~pnxA"|Clip
```

Comment: `set files=%files:~0,4%` sounds more like `%~dA\ ` only. But I might have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: The problem with that is that those are known without the loop, as is what they're getting <space 0x20><double quote 0x22><capital I 0x49><colon 0x3A>. My guess therefore is that they only wanted the path minus the drive letter i.e. "**%files:~4%**

Comment: yeah, that's also a possible interpretion. But `set files=files:~2,4%` seems to solve the issue (see the Klitos' answer) - which would be `%~dA` - which (as you say) is pointless, as the drive letter is explicitely defined before, so well-known.